# Read data from multiple files into a single RDD or Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am having HMP [dataset](https://github.com/wchill/HMP_Dataset). This data set has **14** different folders (categories) and each category has multiple CSV files in it.

I want to read data from all csv files into a single dataframe. Schema for data is

```
 val Tschema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("X", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("Y", IntegerType, nullable = true),
  StructField("Z", IntegerType, true)
 ))
```

I addition i want to add Two more columns to dataframe. First column contains the name of folder(category) containing current CSV and second column contains name of CSV file.

I have tried following code but it did not work properly.

```
val path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/HMP/*"  // Path to all categories
val df =spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)
df.toDF().show(5 , false)
```

output of my code is

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                                                                    _1|                  _2|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|Climb_stairs/Accelerometer-2012-06-06-14-13-20-climb_stairs-m7.txt    |12 38 35            |
|Climb_stairs/Accelerometer-2012-06-06-14-13-20-climb_stairs-m7.txt    |23 56 34            |
|Climb_stairs/Accelerometer-2012-06-06-14-13-20-climb_stairs-m7.txt    |13 36 36            |
|Climb_stairs/Accelerometer-2012-06-06-14-13-20-climb_stairs-m7.txt    |39 57 42            |
|Climb_stairs/Accelerometer-2012-06-06-14-13-20-climb_stairs-m7.txt    |26 51 36            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Here in first column **(_1)** before **\** is part that i want to be on separate column **class** and remain part will be in column **source**. 
On the **_2** part i want to apply schema that I defined.

I want final output to  will look like following.

```
+---+---+---+--------------+---------------------+
|  X|  Y|  Z|         class|               source|
+---+---+---+--------------+---------------------+
| 37| 34| 43|  Climb_stairs|Accelerometer-2011...|
| 05| 39| 34|  Climb_stairs|Accelerometer-2011...|
| 30| 53| 49|  Climb_stairs|Accelerometer-2011...|
+---+---+---+-------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: could you add dataframe .show(false) option to get what you want as source

Comment: @MaheshGupta yes that will not truncate entries. But i want output as mentioned in above Dataframe (table)

Comment: @MaheshGupta I have updated question and code please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at files from local file system. can you include details of what do you get in `df`? Are you running spark in local mode?

If you want to try on Cloudera VM, you can do something like, put two of those csv files into hdfs location by following below steps

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /files
hdfs dfs -put sample.csv sample2.csv /files/
```

Run spark as

```
spark2-shell
val df = spark.read.csv("/files/")
df.show
```

For reading file name and directory, you may need to play with `split` and `input_file_name` functions depending on exact location of files on HDFS.

You could add something as below.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("file_name", split(input_file_name(), "/").getItem(7).cast(StringType))
```

Similarly you can play with `input_file_name` and probably `substr` to grab input directory depending on what part you want.

Comment: this code will give data from CSV files. I additionally want two columns with this output as well. one containing name of directory in which that CSV file is residing and second column contains name of CSV file

Comment: I have updated question and code please check it now

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, basically you need to use `input_file_name` function.

Answer (score 0):

> you could achieve this by using input_file_name with split and reverse reading

**multiple input file**

```
scala>  var df_v = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).load("input_file/*.csv")
scala> df_v.show
+---------------+-------------------+
|             id|           DateTime|
+---------------+-------------------+
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 19:43:23|
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 10:56:43|
|340028465709212|10-01-2018 02:47:11|
|340054675199675|09-01-2018 10:59:10|
|340028465709212|02-01-2018 03:25:35|
|340054675199675|28-12-2017 05:48:04|
|340054675199675|21-12-2017 15:47:51|
|340028465709212|18-12-2017 10:33:04|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|
|340028465709212|12-12-2017 07:04:51|
|340054675199675|06-12-2017 08:52:38|
|       21000101|               null|
|       20991231|               null|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

**apply input_file_name inbuilt function to get filename**

```
scala> var df_v1 =df_v.withColumn("file",input_file_name).withColumn("folder",reverse(split($"file","/"))(1)).withColumn("filename",reverse(split($"file","/"))(0))//.drop("file")
scala> df_v1.show(false)
+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
|id             |DateTime           |file                                      |folder    |filename   |
+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 19:43:23|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340054675199675|15-01-2018 10:56:43|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|10-01-2018 02:47:11|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340054675199675|09-01-2018 10:59:10|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|02-01-2018 03:25:35|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340054675199675|28-12-2017 05:48:04|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340054675199675|21-12-2017 15:47:51|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|18-12-2017 10:33:04|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|16-12-2017 19:55:40|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340028465709212|12-12-2017 07:04:51|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|340054675199675|06-12-2017 08:52:38|file:///home/mahesh/input_file/test.csv   |input_file|test.csv   |
|21000101       |null               |file:///home/mahesh/input_file/so_date.csv|input_file|so_date.csv|
|20991231       |null               |file:///home/mahesh/input_file/so_date.csv|input_file|so_date.csv|
+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Uncomment drop column if you don't want I just keep for clarification.